# Pipe data from TCP socket connection to terminal

Tags: bash, tcp, cat, tail

I have this simple line writing JSON to a TCP server

```
echo "{\"some\":\"json-data\"}" > /dev/tcp/localhost/9091 > cat
```

I would have thought that some connection would be created, and the data would get piped to the terminal/tty, but this doesn't work, the line is just skipped over, and the bash script completes right away.

I also tried:

```
echo "{\"some\":\"json-data\"}" > /dev/tcp/localhost/9091 | tail -f
```

**On my TCP server, I get a connection, but the pipe is quickly broken.**

How can I write a bash command that will stream the data from the TCP server to the bash script?

Comment: This sort of thing is usually done with `nc` or `netcat` or `socat`

Comment: yeah I  am going to resort to that soon. Any idea why the above wouldn't work?

Comment: if you can demonstrate the equivalent command with netcat, that keeps piping data to cat or tail, that would get my vote.

Comment: @thrig you might be interested in the answer provided

Comment: nope. `ls: /dev/tcp: No such file or directory`

Comment: the bash command mentioned is special to bash; bash interprets that path in a special way, it does not actually exist on the filesystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a persistent FD.  This is very awkward in bash... people tend to end up allocating the file numbers by hand.

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/9091
echo "{\"some\":\"json-data\"}" >&3
cat <&3
```

the above assumes the socket is closed after the reply is sent.

Comment: thanks, I saw something similar from Diego here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739196/simple-socket-server-in-bash

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "people tend to end up allocating the file numbers by hand."

Comment: @AlexanderMills Like I just did with the number 3.

Comment: oh, should I pick a file descriptor other than 3? I guess 0,1,2 are stdin, stdout, stderr right?

Comment: @AlexanderMills yes.  3 is fine... if your script doesn't use it for anything else at the same time, is the problem.

Comment: yeah that is my concern, the script may get invoked multiple times, would that cause a problem using 3 everytime as the fd? But I do not use the same fd in the same script.

Comment: @AlexanderMills no, that's fine.

Comment: that's what I thought, but I wasn't entirely sure, need to learn more about how file descriptors work. The same number in different scripts seems to point to different things. :)

Comment: I can confirm this works, hats off to you sir

Comment: any links to light reading on persistent file descriptors?

Comment: @AlexanderMills More information about this technique [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial)